# Who was Hans Bauer who worked on the Perron integral?

Tags: mathematicians

I'm referring to the Hans Bauer who is the author of [this article](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01999447) from 1915 (H. Bauer, "Der Perronsche Integralbegriff und seine Beziehung auf Lebesguesschen" Monatsh. Math. Phys. , 26 (1915) pp. 153–198). When was this man born and when did he die? I'm asking because I have mentioned his name in the beginning of my thesis and I would like to provide the reader with some additional information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hans (Adolf) Bauer was Pauli's private tutor in mathematics and physics, more datails [here](https://books.google.it/books?id=8tUVMSsC9wAC&pg=PA380&lpg=PA380&dq=hans+bauer+mathematician&source=bl&ots=mHT7QSAq2w&sig=ACfU3U0lNI5bZVd5edt3rkdSMk0XQR4yZg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjhleG7z-vpAhVKm6QKHbJqAwsQ6AEwA3oECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=bauer&f=false).

Born in Wien in 1891 became Privatdozent in 1925 and then professor of theoretical physics in 1937 at the Technische Hochscule in Wien. He published paper on relativity heory and wave mechanics; he died in 1953.

He published two books on relativity and wave mechanics:

*Mathematic Einfuhrung in De Gravitationstheorie Einsteins (1922)

*[Grundlagen der Atomphysik](https://www.springer.com/de/book/9783662361221) (1938)

From [here](https://books.google.it/books?id=5mGZno8CvnQC&pg=PA176&lpg=PA176&dq=hans+bauer+wolfgang+pauli&source=bl&ots=FecEL7ZJzr&sig=ACfU3U26j3O7r0qPXZbSPSEncXzondnTRg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiluKzx0evpAhX9SBUIHb65ASMQ6AEwA3oECAsQAQ#v=onepage&q=hans%20bauer%20wolfgang%20pauli&f=false):

> Bauer discussed introducing Einstein's principle in of general relativity in high school instruction. He also gave lectures on general relativity at the Verein deutscher Mathematiker uns Physiker at the university and expanded them into a book (1922) which was intended to form a bridge between many popular expositions and the highly technical ones. His research on Einstein's equations resulted in a very lenghtly, regrettably almost totally overlooked, study of spherically symmetric fluid solutions with a linear equation of state, and later in a similar one of the general static spherically symmetric solution.